# How to run a Gradle task after apks are produced in Android Studio?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The following task (in build.gradle of an app's module) seems to run always before the apk is produced:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
            def releaseBuildTask = tasks.create(name: "debug") {
            println("....................  test   ..............................")
        }
        releaseBuildTask.mustRunAfter variant.assemble
    }
}
```

Could anyone offer a tip on how to run a task after the apks are produced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try add this in you `app/build.gradle`

```
assembleDebug.doLast {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
            def releaseBuildTask = tasks.create(name: "debug") {
                println("....................  test   ..............................")
            }
            releaseBuildTask.mustRunAfter variant.assemble
        }
    }
    println "build finished"
}
```

invoke the build command and specify the task `assembleDebug`

`./gradlew assembleDebug`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  I migrated to Android Studio from Eclipse yesterday. The difference is quite significant.

Comment: Does this have to invoked via the command line? Will the `doLast` block still execute if we're using the green run button in android studio?

Comment: @11m0 run the task from command line or android studio is totally the same.

Comment: You must put this command inside afterEvaluate starting from gradle 2.2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/52915218/8942811

Comment: Android tasks are typically created in the "afterEvaluate" phase. Starting from 2.2, those tasks also include "assembleDebug" and "assembleRelease". To access such tasks, the user will need to use an afterEvaluate closure

Answer (score 18):

> Android tasks are typically created in the "afterEvaluate" phase.
>   Starting from gradle 2.2, those tasks also include "assembleDebug" and
>   "assembleRelease". To access such tasks, the user will need to use an
>   afterEvaluate closure:
>
> `afterEvaluate {
>       assembleDebug.dependsOn someTask 
>   }`

source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219732#c32

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution that works, to copy the release APK into the project root automatically on build completion.

```
    android {
        ...
        task copyReleaseApk(type: Copy) {
            from 'build/outputs/apk'
            into '..' // Into the project root, one level above the app folder
            include '**/*release.apk'
        }

        afterEvaluate {
            packageRelease.finalizedBy(copyReleaseApk)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this in you app/build.gradle, Then after assembleRelease is completed, you can copy the file to the directory you specified.

```
project.tasks.configureEach { Task theTask ->
if (theTask.name == 'assembleRelease') {

    theTask.doLast {

        copy {
            from youInputPath // This can be the apk file path or mapping file path
            into youOutputPath
        }
        
    }
}
```