# Android Studio: sound notification on build success

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

Is it possible to play a sound after my app was compiled and deployed on smartphone in Android Studio / IntelliJ

My workaround is to play a sound inside of `onStart()` method of my StartActivity, but I have to implement (copy/paste) this pattern for every new project. Not realy nice solution.

Comment: Since Android Studio uses Gradle for the builds, if you can figure out how to make a Gradle task play a sound, you should be able to chain that into the build process.

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74055895/619673

Answer (score 33):

In Android Studio, go into Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications, go down to Gradle Build (Logging) and check the Read aloud box.

This will speak Gradle build finished in x minutes and x seconds when your build is complete.

Comment: Could not find in Android Studio 3.4.2. Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: This only supports to mac

Comment: Well, I activated this last week (thanks to your answer). I had to trace this answer again to learn how to deactivate it. It gets annoying real quick.

Comment: Note that for build failure this solution says nothing

Comment: it will says BUILD FAILED in xxs for android studio version Dolphin 2021.3.1

Answer (score 2):

A blend of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66226491/8636969 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63632498/8636969 that's very simple for mac:

```
gradle.buildFinished { BuildResult buildResult ->
    try {
        "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff".execute()
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
}
```

in your `build.gradle`. This just plays the Submarine sounds everytime a build finishes.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126952/14623286) we need to call the task inside `afterEvaluate`.
And since I can't comment, I will put my working code here. This code works for windows.

You can add this to your `app/.gradle` file inside `android{ }` tag :

```
afterEvaluate {
    gradle.buildFinished{ BuildResult buildResult ->
        if (buildResult.failure) {
            ['powershell', """(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\\failed_notif.wav").PlaySync();"""].execute()
            println("failed doing task")
        } else {
            ['powershell', """(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\\succeed_notif.wav").PlaySync();"""].execute()
            println("build finished")
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this method can only run with `.wav` file. If you want to use an `.mp3` you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895428/how-to-play-mp3-with-powershell-simple/51964833).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can do it like this (in build.gradle):

```
gradle.buildFinished { BuildResult buildResult ->
    // Beep on finish
    try {
        String filename = buildResult.getFailure() ? 'Alarm10.wav' : 'Alarm02.wav'
        ['powershell', '-c', """(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\\Windows\\Media\\${filename}").PlaySync();"""].execute()
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
}
```

Comment: Where should we put this code?
In project level or app level
and inside which tag?

Comment: @MayankSharma, anywhere in the root of build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

On mac based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/etiennestuder/5653547be88410d914fbf0700d4d6be4) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188483/i-am-not-able-to-find-init-d-folder-in-my-gradle-folder-where-to-search-fo) to find the folder do:

Create file `speak.gradle` with below content inside `~/.gradle/init.d` folder (if you can't find `init.d` folder, you can create it)

**speak.gradle**

```
// When runnning a Gradle build in the background, it is convenient to be notified immediately 
// via voice once the build has finished - without having to actively switch windows to find out - 
// and being told the actual exception in case of a build failure.

// Put this file into the folder ~/.gradle/init.d to enable the acoustic notifications for all builds

gradle.addBuildListener(new BuildAdapter() {
    
    @Override
    void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
        def projectName = gradle.rootProject.name
        if (result.failure) {
            playSound('Submarine.aiff')
            def e = getExceptionParts(result)
            "say '$projectName build failed: ${e.first} ${e.second}.'".execute()
        } else {
            if (projectName != "buildSrc") {
                playSound('Glass.aiff')
                "say '$projectName build successful.'".execute()
            }
        }
    }

    private Tuple2<String, String> getExceptionParts(BuildResult result) {
        def exception = result.failure
        if (exception.cause != null) {
            exception = exception.cause
        }
        def className = exception.class.simpleName
        def of = className.indexOf('Exception')
        new Tuple2<String, String>(className.substring(0, of), className.substring(of))
    }

    private void playSound(def sound) {
        "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/$sound".execute()
        sleep(100)
    }
    
})
```

you can simplify more the sound to `done` and `fail`

Comment: For a simplified variant: `gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
    if (buildResult.failure) { "say Build failed.".execute() }
    else { "say Ok.".execute() }}`