# I am not able to find (init.d ) folder in my .gradle folder ! where to search for it?

Tags: android, gradle

I decided to *Configure offline build dependencies* in my android.I am following the documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline guidance.

> I successfully did the **"Download and unzip offline components"**
> step as the first step.
>
> I have to **"Include offline components in your Gradle project"** as
> the second step

.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWmC5.png)

but unfortunately, I am not able to find the exact folder where I have to create the file and paste the code inside it.
my folders view is this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NLri.png)

could anyone plz let me know what exactly I need to do? should I create a folder on my own or need to explore anywhere else?
I am using android 3.5

Comment: `C:\Users\talib\.gradle\ ` seems OK. Create the folder, create the file and try again. There's no risk. It would be faster to try than to write this question :)

Comment: @KrystianG thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to create the `init.d` folder at this location and place your init script in it.
Note that the script itself needs to have the `.gradle` extension for a Groovy one and `.gradle.kts` for a Kotlin one.