# Executing a task after a signed bundle is created

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to take the generated signed bundle from Android Studio and generate all apks and install them on every device that is connected to my computer at that time.

I know how to generate the apks and install them but I don't know how to run that script after a signed bundle is created. I only want this to run when I use Build -> Generate signed bundle/apk and choose a bundle and the production release flavor.

Can I do that with gradle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

> Android tasks are typically created in the "afterEvaluate" phase. Starting from gradle 2.2, those tasks also include "assembleDebug" and
>   "assembleRelease". To access such tasks, the user will need to use an
>   afterEvaluate closure:
>
> ```
>  afterEvaluate {
>        assembleDebug.dependsOn someTask    }
> ```

source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219732#c32

try add this in you `app/build.gradle`

```
afterEvaluate {
    assembleRelease.doLast {
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                def releaseBuildTask = tasks.create(name: "release") {
                    println("....................  test   ..............................")
                }
                releaseBuildTask.mustRunAfter variant.assemble
            }
        }
        println "build finished"
    }
}
```

invoke the build command and specify the task `assembleRelease`

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Thanks. Where in my gradle file do I put this? I put it inside the `android` section and outside of it and I just get errors like `Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.`

Comment: @casolorz put it outside of `android` and inside the `afterEvaluate`

Comment: When I put it outside the `android` section I get `Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: @Casolorz have u resolved this, I have to do same